# Python list input from stdin takes only 2048 elements

Tags: python-2.7, stdin

```
input=map(int,raw_input().split())
```

I input more than 13,000 elements from the stdin, but on printing the length of list it shows that it has only 2048 elements in it. Why is it so? Is it somehow related to the size of the input buffer?

Comment: What does your input look like? How are you passing it? (Remember that `raw_input()` only reads one line – use `sys.stdin.read()` if you want to get the entire stdin.)

Comment: Not sure it'll make a difference but you could consider increasing the stdin buffer size.